# How send parameters with decimal point in url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I’m using Backbone.js and Rails.

In Backbone.js I use HTML5 push state to set filter parameters in a url.

When the page is reloading I want to pass these parameters to Rails.

I encoded a parameter `lat:34.34+lng:45.23` using JavaScript’s `encodeURIComponent`. It encoded:

```
/users/nearby/lat:34.34+lng:45.23/
```

as:

```
/users/nearby/lat%3A34.34%2Blng%3A45.23
```

but this route is not found.

If I delete the points from url, it works.

How can I send parameters with a decimal point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` is not a character that has to be encoded. Is this causing issues server side?

See here for more details:
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problems adding an "extra" slash to the end of the url.
In your encoded url it is missing.

Hope this helps

Comment: In my case, yes it helped, thanks. I have the number to be passed at the last query string.

Answer (score -1):

One manifestation of this problem is in URL pattern matching, where the Query Param is expected (i.e. matched) to be an integer. This does not match a number with a decimal point. So you get a 404 (URL not found).